# How to fix (node:12388) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, http-headers

I am new to nodes.I have install nosejs version v12.4.0, npm 6.9.0 , http-server 0.11.1 and visual studio code.I want to open my hello word project with my http-server,it is in Visual studio code. But I receive the below error

**ERROR**

[2019-06-21T05:20:18.280Z] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763"
(node:11596) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

I tried **npm install node-gyp** to fix the header problem but no success.

Also I have try to use different browsers eg. chrome, firefox , explore but no success.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hello Word </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expected to see "Hello Word" in any of the browsers.I am using windows 10. Kindly assist

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Node version 12 depracated OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers, which is used in http-server. Issue is listed at:
https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/537

https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0066_outgoingmessage_prototype_headers_outgoingmessage_prototype_headernames

Using node 12.0.0 I get the same error using http-server. Switching to 10.11.0 removes the error.

Comment: For future reference... per the link, as an example, instead of using obj._headers, use obj.getHeaders() to get the headers object.  So replace the property name "._headers" with the function ".getHeaders()".  Same results using either one except using the function is the supported method and removes the deprecation warning.

Comment: While working with angular micro front end application, I received the micro app not render inside master. After downgrade node js to 10.x it's working. thanks

Comment: Also, works with latest **LTS v10** (_lts/dubnium_ -> **v10.22.0**)

Answer (score 16):

Those who are facing this problem in `FreeCodeCamp` exercise, the issue is in the `server.js` file. The solution is to replace `._headers` with `.getHeaders()`, as the error is telling us that `._headers` has been deprecated.
e.g. in `server.js`, instead of -

```
// filter out CORS Headers
var hs = Object.keys(res._headers)
  .filter(h => !h.match(/^access-control-\w+/));
var hObj = {};
hs.forEach(h => {hObj[h] = res._headers[h]});
delete res._headers['strict-transport-security'];
```

use the following -

```
// filter out CORS Headers
var hs = Object.keys(res.getHeaders())
  .filter(h => !h.match(/^access-control-\w+/));
var hObj = {};
hs.forEach(h => {hObj[h] = res.getHeaders()[h]});
delete res.getHeaders()['strict-transport-security'];
```

Summary: replace all `._headers` with `.getHeaders()`.

Comment: Also, add `app.disable('x-powered-by')` to your `server.js` file, after `var app = express()`, to pass the test immediately or in single attempt.

Answer (score 6):

I had some issue with browser-sync. When I started project I got warning from node (**[DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated**) every time. But when I updated my browser-synk dependencies to **"browser-sync": "^2.26.13"** my project started without any warning.

Answer (score 4):

For those getting it everytime they start their project,
Run: `npm i browser-sync`

Answer (score 4):

for me helped run my project as `node --trace-deprecation /var/www/my-script-path` and open it webpage. after i read in console path to depricated code and it module name. for me it old version express.js. after upgrade it error is not show.

Answer (score 2):

you can update node to ver 17,
i solved my issue by this solution