# Deprecation Warning in Node Js

Tags: html, node.js, deprecation-warning

I'm getting this type of **Deprecation Warning**, when i was creating *Admin Panel* for my android app.

---

Here's the code for it-

```
 DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

this error was displayed in CMD.

I've already tried putting `node --trace-deprecation ...` but it gives no results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix (node:12388) \[DEP0066\] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype.\_headers is deprecated in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697360/how-to-fix-node12388-dep0066-deprecationwarning-outgoingmessage-prototype)

Comment: @kmgt No, it doesn't. I still can't figure out the solution for that from that answer which you linked. They're talking abut header part, but my problem is a little different

Comment: soo... did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was using `express`. I updated my all project version of `node.js`, `npm` and `pm2`. But I use pm2 low version to deploy my project. and I saw this message. When I deploy my project with new version of pm2, it solved.
so there are something running low version according to other tool versions. Find your low version tool and update it.