# Connecting SQL database on Azure with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database

I am studying to become a full stack web developer on NodeJS, Express, EJS. Now that I am almost done with my course, I thought I should tackle my dream project which is to create a web app for our local small non-profit library(~6500books). The biggest functionality on the web app is browsing the collection. They are using an SQL database and gave an mbd file to work with. I created an Azure SQL server and database and via several manipulations uploaded the database file there. I see all the tables, can query it, and all looks right there.

Now I am trying to figure out how to connect the Azure database to NodeJS (it is the only back-end I am familiar with), so I can fetch data from Azure database and start building front with React.

I created the following app following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvy_BlgwfLI  tutorial. It worked fine when I created it but now that I open it again(from same IP address), my http://localhost:1433/main says CANNOT GET/main, the home route with Hello World works fine.

I am getting the following msg in console:
Main Books API is running on port1433
(node:14700) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Here are my files:
-------------------------------package.json

```
{
  "name": "dbname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "api.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "2.8.1",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mssql": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "author": "my name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

---------------------------------------api.js

```
const dboperations = require("./dboperations");
let db = require("./dboperations");
let Main = require("./main");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("express");


const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api", router);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')
  })

router.use((request, response, next)=>{
    console.log("middleware");
    next();
})

router.route("/main").get((request, response)=>{
    dboperations.getMain().then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
    //response.json(result);
})
})

let port = process.env.PORT || 1433;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Main Books API is running on port" + port);
```

------------------------------bdconfig.js

```
const config = {
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    server: "servername",
    database: "dbname",
    options:{
        encrypt: true,
        
    },
    port: 1433
}

module.exports = config;
```

--------------------dboperations.js

```
var config = require("./dbconfig");
const sql = require("mssql");


async function getMain(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let products = await pool.request().query("SELECT * from dbo.tblMain");
        return products.recordset;

    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getMain: getMain
}
```

--------------------main.js

```
class Main {
    constructor (ID, Book, Volume, Author){
        this.ID = ID, 
        this.Book = Book, 
        this.Volume = Volume, 
        this.Author = Author, 
        
    }
}

module.exports = Main;
```

I will really appreciate if you can help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to get started with Azure db and Node (maybe some other way/modules?). Any suggestions of what I should be doing are appreciated, and any resources/tutorials! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129479) by [ch1pn3ss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483670/ch1pn3ss) on stackoverflow. This error is occurred because of Node Version.

Switch to node version `10.11.0` or try with any version other than your existing node version.